# Trying to understand pointwise convergence in the symmetry group of X

Tags: group-theory, general-topology

Apologies for a question that I'm sure is very silly, but I'm not an expert on symmetry groups and this example is confusing me.

So, suppose we define the following functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$: $f_n(x)=x+\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}(x\notin\mathbb{Q})$, $f(x)=x$; where $\mathbb{1}(x\notin\mathbb{Q})$ represents the indicator that $x$ is an irrational number. Clearly, as functions, $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly and, in particular, convergence is pointwise. Notice that each of these functions is a well defined bijection.

Now, lets look at these functions as elements of the symmetry group of $\mathbb{R}$, $Sym(\mathbb{R})$ (which we can, since they are bijections from the reals to the reals). It is my understanding that the topology of pointwise convergence for $Sym(\mathbb{R})$ has as a sub-basis the sets of the form $B(x,y)=\{g:g(x)=y\}$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $B(x,x)$ is a nbhd of $f$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So, if $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ there should be an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ $f_n\in B(x,x)$. This is clearly impossible since $f_n(x)\neq x$ for all $n$ when $x$ is irrational. So it seems that, in the pointwise convergence topology of the symmetric group of $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ does NOT converge to $f$.

So, am I missing something, or are pointwise convergence of functions and pointwise convergence (in the sense of a group) different notions of "pointwise convergence"?

Comment: It's not "pointwise convergence in the sense of group", it's pointwise convergence for the discrete topology of $\mathbf{R}$. So it's not surprising that it does not match with pointwise convergence with the usual topology.

Comment: I see, I guess the terminology confused me then. So, in the context of the symmetric group, "pointwise convergence" means "pointwise convergence as functions when the underlying space (say, the reals in this example) has the discrete topology"?

Comment: If by $Sym(\mathbb{R})$ you mean the set of *all* bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, then the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ has nothing to do with anything.  It could be any arbitrary set of that cardinality, and an arbitrary set has no natural topological structure except the discrete one.

Comment: You're comparing with the topology induced by inclusion into $\mathbf{R}^{\mathbf{R}_\delta}$ and into $(\mathbf{R}_\delta)^{\mathbf{R}_\delta}$, both with the product topology. Here $\mathbf{R}_\delta$ means $\mathbf{R}$ with discrete topology.